# Code generator for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, code-generation

I have been using CodeSmith for .NET code generation from DB. Is there any similar code generation tool for SQLite DB which generates code for objective-c?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I presume you're aware of the [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) approach to such things?

Comment: You could always write your own templates for objective-c. CodeSmith Generator does have a SQLiteSchemaProvider that ships with the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Objective-C based repository for SQLite has a simple bash script that will read an SQLite database and generate the appropriate ORM models for you.  The URL is https://github.com/ziminji/objective-c-sql-query-builder

All you need to do is configure a small properties file that will tell the bash script where the SQLite database is on your hard-drive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).   It is built in, very fast, extremely well documented, and there are tons of examples of how to use it.

It, however, doesn't generate code.  Code generation is generally awful;   machine generated code is often overly verbose, poorly formatted, and difficult to debug.  Worse, once you edit the code, you can't re-generate without risk of conflict (at best).

Core Data, like Interface Builder, take the approach that you should be able to model a bit of functionality in something that is archived during compilation and unarchived at runtime.  Better yet, the modeling aspects of both IB and Core Data do *nothing* that can't be done in code, if you really wanted.  That is, there is no magic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing code-first or model-first style development, the [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is by far the best way to go on OS X/iOS. However, Core Data is not an ORM and so is not the right solution for working with a DB with an existing (non-Core Data) schema. If this is your situation, Objective-C's dynamic nature means that code generation is rarely necessary. Implementing an Active Record pattern is pretty straight forward. Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/activerecord/) project for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what Barry and bbum have said about Core Data.  It's very useful.  However, it's not a panacea.  There may be times when you need to access a pre-existing SQLite database, and migrating it to Core Data would be total overkill.  In these cases, you should use the [Flying Meat Database wrapper](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), aka "FMDB".  It's clean and easy to use.

Comment: thank you for understanding my question. other guys didn't understand my question I guess.